# How to effectively interview advertise open roles when attending virtual industry conference

Tags: recruitment, networking

I registered for an upcoming industry [cybersecurity conference](https://www.isaca.org/conferences/isaca-conference-north-america?cid=sem_2003930&Appeal=sem&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq7nn79_Z7wIVIfHjBx2EiQ9vEAAYASAAEgJb8fD_BwE) along with my team members. Due to Covid 19, this year the conference will be virtual. In the past when I attended, there were opportunities for professional networking.

The information security team at my workplace where I am the technical lead is looking to hire several additional folks, ranging from internal pen testers to senior security engineers. In the past, security conferences such as DEF CON have led to candidates for which we ultimately hired. With virtual conference, strategies we used in the past to attract candidates such as Kali demos, simulated black hat hacking exercises etc. are not feasible. This is also the first time I may be doing informal chats / interviews with prospective employees in an environment that is not only outside the traditional office, but in a virtual event where networking is a bonus benefit , not the main objective of conference attendance. My goal if networking is to help market our company and open roles on my team with possibility of making successful recruit a bonus.

**In a virtual environment at a professional conference, what are some strategies to effectively market open roles for a technical position?**

**If marketing / recruiting tools such as Kali Linux, or pen testing CTF demos are infeasible in a virtual environment , what can be used as substitutes?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Sponsorship Prospectus](https://www.isaca.org/-/media/files/isacadp/project/isaca/training-and-events/sponsor/isaca-conference-north-america-2021-sponsorship-prospectus.pdf) they mention virtual sponsor booths for $5,000 USD. You could do a virtual ad for $500.

The conference schedule has daily 30m networking breaks as well. Not really sure what that would look like tho.

A lot of conferences will have a Slack channel or a Twitter hashtag that they encourage people to post things under. Participating in those kinds of thing would be another way to do networking in lieu of in-person networking. I don't see anything about this on their website but a lot of things like this are usually promoted only during the conference itself. Maybe [#isaca](https://twitter.com/hashtag/isaca?lang=en) idk.

They have a "Virtual Headshots & Photo Booth". Maybe y'all could upload pics with a "we're hiring" text blurb on them.